# Application Stop When Google Calendar Oauth

Tags: java, linux, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, centos7

The application freezes while Google Calendar API authentication is in progress.

Below is my source code.

```
private final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Calendar API Java Quickstart";
    private java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR;
    private FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;
    private final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;
    private final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);

    @Value("#{config['path.googleAuth']}")
    private String googleAuthPath;

    public void setGoogleData(String member_id_num) throws Exception{
        String userHome = "";
        if(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().indexOf("win") >= 0) {
            userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
        }else if(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().indexOf("linux") >= 0) {
            userHome = googleAuthPath;
        }else {
            userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
        }
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(userHome,".credentials_sellers/calendar-java-quickstart_sellers"+File.separator+member_id_num);
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        log.info("DATA_STORE_DIR=" + DATA_STORE_DIR);
    }

    public Credential authorize(String member_id_num) throws Exception {
        setGoogleData(member_id_num);

        InputStream in = GoogleCalendarService.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");

        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        log.info("clientSecrets = " + clientSecrets);

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
                clientSecrets, SCOPES).setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY).setAccessType("offline").build();

        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");

        log.info("Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }
```

my client_secret.json

```
{
    "installed": {
        "client_id": "459740830795-lm5pnqsule6jg4ufu3uvnufgr7tdajn6.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "project_id": "the-sellers-255504",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret": "L3kDYxfDoSDUG5wM3XEMDi9H",
        "redirect_uris": ["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", "http://localhost", "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx", "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8090", "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx", "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8090"]
    }
}
```

In my local environment, the test was successful.
However, the website hangs because I try to link it to a Linux server.

help me please ....

Comment: Hello 셀러스, at what line does the code hang? Do you receive any output (error logs)? Kindly let me know so I can help you troubleshoot the issue. Cheers

Comment: Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");

hang code

Comment: There is no error message ...

Comment: The line of code you have issues with is the one that opens a new browser window where you are able to manually complete the OAuth authentication flow. In case it doesn't automatically open, you should see a message printed by your program describing what the login URL is. Do you notice any of those? Thanks